# Reading a File From the Computer

Tags: java

Now I have this error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
    at Lotto1.main(Lotto1.java:37)

Line 37:  arr[count][0] = s.next() + ""+ s.next();

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {

        File f = new File("D:\\Filipe\\Project Final\\src\\database_lotto.txt");
        Scanner s;
        try {
            s = new Scanner(f);

           BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
            int lines = 0;
            while (reader.readLine() != null) {
                lines++;
            }
            reader.close();

            arr  = new String[lines][3];

            int count = 0;
            //while theres still another line
            while (s.hasNextLine()){
                arr[count][0] = s.next() + ""+ s.next();
                arr[count][1] = s.next();
                arr[count][2] = s.next();
               count++;                   
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
           System.out.println("File does not exist");
        }
```

Comment: put the file in the same folder from where you are running the code or pass the file to the file reader instead of the name of the file.. so do  `BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));`

Comment: Why are you reading what appears to be the same file twice, and in two different ways (Scanner and FileReader)?

Comment: @PaulGrime technically he is trying to read one and open the other :D

Comment: Isn't the Scanner used for reading (s.hasNextLine() ...) and the FileReader used for reading (via reader.readLine() ...)?

Comment: Hm Maybe he wants to read one file and write it to another? He [sure](http://memecrunch.com/meme/4LUD/op-will-deliver/image.png) will tell us :)

Comment: I made some changes on the code, but still not working :(

Answer (score 3):

You didn't put the right path into the FileReader only into File f, you can pass f into the Filereader instead of repeating the path:

```
File f = new File("D:\\database_lotto.txt");
[...]
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
```

Comment: I changed it and now I have another error:                    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4 at Lotto1.main(Lotto1.java:37)

Line 37: arr[count][0] = s.next() + ""+ s.next();

Comment: Everytime you call "s.next()" this advances the internal "line-index" maybe that causes the error. You should call "s.next()" only once in every loop round.

Comment: I changed it, and still the same problem :(

Comment: Below is the sample txt file:                                                                           Daily Millions 3 1.00
Irish Lotto 2 1.50
Euro Millions 1 2.00
Millionaire Raffle 1 20.00