# Read a file from a host computer

Tags: java

I'm trying to read a file from the computer that is in the same folder as the source code and when I run the code is saying: File does not exist
Can you help me ?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Lotto1 {
  static String[][] arr;
  static String name, number;
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File f = new File("D:\\Filipe\\Project Final\\src\\database_lotto.txt.txt");
    Scanner s;
    try {
      s = new Scanner(f);
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
      int lines = 0;
      while(reader.readLine() != null) {
        lines++;
      }
      reader.close();
      arr = new String[lines][3];
      int count = 0;
      //while theres still another line
      while(s.hasNextLine()) {
        arr[count][0] = s.next() + "" + s.next();
        arr[count][1] = s.next();
        arr[count][2] = s.next();
        count++;
      }
    } catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
      System.out.println("File does not exist");
    }
```

Comment: database_lotto.txt.txt? You sure it's not supposed to be database_lotto.txt?

Comment: Isn't this the same question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15854085/reading-a-file-from-the-computer

Comment: Even with database_lotto.txt it's the same problem.

Comment: If the file is contained within the Jar file, you need to be using Class#getResource instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've inferred what you're trying to do and recoded it, but this implementation will read the file if it is where you say it is.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String filename = "database_lotto.txt";
    final File lottoFile = new File(filename);

    try (final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(lottoFile)) {
        final List<String[]> storage = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            storage.add(scanner.nextLine().split(" "));
        }
    }catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("File not found :(");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you on Unix/Linux machine?

It is better to use File.separator instead of \, because File.separator uses the system char for a directory (\ on Win, / on Linux etc.)

Use File.exists() to check if file is there, before using it.

Comment: Then double backslashed should work. Therefore, it seems that your path is incorrect.

Comment: **it doesn´t work :(**